# Creating ring shaped mask in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 256x256 pixel data. each pixel is 4 unit. I am trying to create an annular or ring shaped mask function in python with numpy. The function should take inner and outer radius, dimension of x array and y array and  center. So far I wrote this:

```
def createAnnularMask(dimx, dimy, center, big_radius, small_radius):

    Y, X = np.ogrid[:dimx, :dimy]
    distance_from_center = np.sqrt((X - center[0])**2 + (Y-center[1])**2)

    mask =  small_radius <= distance_from_center <= big_radius

    return mask
```

But when I am trying to call the function with arguments, it returns me the following error:

```
createAnnularMask(256, 256, [128,128], 413, 80)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-65514f563633> in <module>()
----> 1 ring = createAnnularMask(256, 256, center, big_radius, small_radius)

<ipython-input-39-d7207a35bc48> in createAnnularMask(dimx, dimy, center, big_radius, small_radius)
      4     distance_from_center = np.sqrt((X - center[0])**2 + (Y-center[1])**2)
      5 
----> 6     mask =  small_radius <= distance_from_center <= big_radius
      7 
      8     return mask

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Could you ease point what I am doing wrong here and how to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do compound comparisons with numpy arrays. Change that line to the following:

```
mask = (small_radius <= distance_from_center) & \
    (distance_from_center <= big_radius)
```

Comment: Also - `np.logical_and(small_radius <= distance_from_center, distance_from_center<= big_radius)`